# Getting StackOverflow exception while reading stringlist in newly hooked LoadResString method

Tags: delphi, winapi, hook, resourcestring

For reference - following is my code, where I am getting StackOverflow exception in NewLoadResString function. The case is like I have creted two stringlist i.e. RecStrNameIdMap and NewStringValueList.
Here RecStrNameIdMap is hash string list to store name and string Identifier mapping. So that I can refer Resource string name for its Identifier i.e ID.

NewStringValueList is a string list which contains new values for few of the Resourcestrings.

I have hooked up NewLoadResString method on system.LoadResString method. In new method I am checking if I have new value for given resourcestring in NewStringValueList then get that value and return new instead of old declared value.

Stack Overflow exception occurs on line *

> if  RecStrNameIdMap.IndexOfName(IntToStr(ResStringRec^.Identifier)) >
>   -1 then

*
Can anyone please check why I am getting this error.

```
unit UnitTest;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, IniFiles, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;


type
  TMethodHook = class
  private
    aOriginal : packed array[ 0..4 ] of byte;
    pOldProc, pNewProc : pointer;
    pPosition : PByteArray;
  public
    constructor Create( pOldProc, pNewProc : pointer );
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;


var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

ResourceString
  RS_1 = 'ABC';
  RS_2 = 'XYZ';

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  aMethodHook: TMethodHook;
  RecStrNameIdMap: THashedStringList;
  NewStringValueList: TStringList;

  {Hookup aNewProcedure on aOriginalProcedure}
  procedure RegisterProcedures(aOriginalProcedure, aNewProcedure: pointer);
  begin
    if Assigned(aOriginalProcedure) and Assigned(aNewProcedure) then
      aMethodHook := TMethodHook.Create( aOriginalProcedure, aNewProcedure);
  end;

  {Replacement for System.LoadResString}
  function NewLoadResString(ResStringRec: PResStringRec): String;
  var
    Buffer: array [0..4095] of char;
  begin
    if ResStringRec = nil then Exit;
    if ResStringRec.Identifier >= 64 * 1024 then
    begin
      Result := PChar(ResStringRec.Identifier);
    end
    else
    begin
      if RecStrNameIdMap.IndexOfName(IntToStr(ResStringRec^.Identifier)) > -1 then
      begin
        Result := NewStringValueList.Values[
          RecStrNameIdMap.Values[IntToStr(ResStringRec^.Identifier)]];
      end
      else
      begin
        SetString(Result, Buffer,
          LoadString(FindResourceHInstance(ResStringRec.Module^),
            ResStringRec.Identifier, Buffer, SizeOf(Buffer)));
      end;
    end;
  end;

  procedure CreateNameIdMapping;
  begin
    {This is done to get string name from ID}
    RecStrNameIdMap.CaseSensitive := False;
    RecStrNameIdMap.Add(Inttostr(PResStringRec(RS_2)^.Identifier)+'='+'XYZ');
  end;

begin
  aMethodHook := nil;
  try
    RecStrNameIdMap := THashedStringList.Create;
    NewStringValueList := TStringList.Create;

    CreateNameIdMapping;

    {Create new value list for ResourceStrings}
    NewStringValueList.Add('XYZ'+'='+'new value for ResourceString RS_2');
    RegisterProcedures(@System.LoadResString, @NewLoadResString);

    {This should return 'new value for ResourceString RS_2' instead of 'XYZ'}
    ShowMessage(RS_2);

    {This should return 'ABC' - no change in value}
    ShowMessage(RS_1);
  finally
    aMethodHook.Free;
    RecStrNameIdMap.Free;
    NewStringValueList.Free;
  end;
end;

{ TMethodHook }

constructor TMethodHook.Create(pOldProc, pNewProc: pointer);
var
  iOffset : integer;
  iMemProtect : cardinal;
  i : integer;
begin
  Self.pOldProc := pOldProc;
  Self.pNewProc := pNewProc;

  pPosition := pOldProc;
  iOffset := integer( pNewProc ) - integer( pointer( pPosition ) ) - 5;

  for i := 0 to 4 do aOriginal[ i ] := pPosition^[ i ];

  VirtualProtect( pointer( pPosition ), 5, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE,
    @iMemProtect );

  pPosition^[ 0 ] := $E9;
  pPosition^[ 1 ] := byte( iOffset );
  pPosition^[ 2 ] := byte( iOffset shr 8 );
  pPosition^[ 3 ] := byte( iOffset shr 16 );
  pPosition^[ 4 ] := byte( iOffset shr 24 );
end;

destructor TMethodHook.Destroy;
var
  i : integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to 4 do pPosition^[ i ] := aOriginal[ i ];
  inherited;
end;

end.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that the replacing procedure cannot be a nested routine.
As stated in the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Procedural_Types):

> Procedural types allow you to treat procedures and functions as values that can be assigned to variables or passed to other procedures and functions.

...

> Nested procedures and functions (routines declared within other routines) cannot be used as procedural values, nor can predefined procedures and functions.

A procedural type is a Pointer. While a nested routine cannot be used as procedural type, I assume that a Pointer to a nested routine cannot be used as a procedure parameter or this action may have unpredictable result like in this case.
The procedure is hooked correctly (you did); I extracted the procedure `NewLoadResString` and the *stackoverflow* error does not happen anymore.
The `resourcestring` which pops up is always the old one but I made no changes in the `NewLoadResString` procedure.
The entire edited unit follows.

```pascal
unit UnitTest;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, IniFiles, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    RecStrNameIdMap: THashedStringList;
    NewStringValueList: TStringList;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;


type
  TMethodHook = class
  private
    aOriginal : packed array[ 0..4 ] of byte;
    pOldProc, pNewProc : pointer;
    pPosition : PByteArray;
  public
    constructor Create( pOldProc, pNewProc : pointer );
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;


var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

ResourceString
  RS_1 = 'ABC';
  RS_2 = 'XYZ';


{Replacement for System.LoadResString}
function NewLoadResString(ResStringRec: PResStringRec): String;
var
  Buffer: array [0..4095] of char;
begin
  if ResStringRec = nil then Exit;
  if ResStringRec.Identifier >= 64 * 1024 then
  begin
    Result := PChar(ResStringRec.Identifier);
  end
  else
  begin
    if RecStrNameIdMap.IndexOfName(IntToStr(ResStringRec^.Identifier)) > -1 then
    begin
      Result := NewStringValueList.Values[
        RecStrNameIdMap.Values[IntToStr(ResStringRec^.Identifier)]];
    end
    else
    begin
      SetString(Result, Buffer,
        LoadString(FindResourceHInstance(ResStringRec.Module^),
          ResStringRec.Identifier, Buffer, SizeOf(Buffer)));
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  aMethodHook: TMethodHook;

  {Hookup aNewProcedure on aOriginalProcedure}
  procedure RegisterProcedures(aOriginalProcedure, aNewProcedure: pointer);
  begin
    if Assigned(aOriginalProcedure) and Assigned(aNewProcedure) then
      aMethodHook := TMethodHook.Create( aOriginalProcedure, aNewProcedure);
  end;

  procedure CreateNameIdMapping;
  begin
    {This is done to get string name from ID}
    RecStrNameIdMap.CaseSensitive := False;
    RecStrNameIdMap.Add(Inttostr(PResStringRec(RS_2)^.Identifier)+'='+'XYZ');
  end;

begin
  aMethodHook := nil;
  RecStrNameIdMap := THashedStringList.Create;
  NewStringValueList := TStringList.Create;
  try
    CreateNameIdMapping;

    {Create new value list for ResourceStrings}
    NewStringValueList.Add('XYZ'+'='+'new value for ResourceString RS_2');
    RegisterProcedures(@System.LoadResString, @NewLoadResString);

    {This should return 'new value for ResourceString RS_2' instead of 'XYZ'}
    ShowMessage(RS_2);

    {This should return 'ABC' - no change in value}
    ShowMessage(RS_1);
  finally
    aMethodHook.Free;
    RecStrNameIdMap.Free;
    NewStringValueList.Free;
  end;
end;

{ TMethodHook }

constructor TMethodHook.Create(pOldProc, pNewProc: pointer);
var
  iOffset : integer;
  iMemProtect : cardinal;
  i : integer;
begin
  Self.pOldProc := pOldProc;
  Self.pNewProc := pNewProc;

  pPosition := pOldProc;
  iOffset := integer( pNewProc ) - integer( pointer( pPosition ) ) - 5;

  for i := 0 to 4 do aOriginal[ i ] := pPosition^[ i ];

  VirtualProtect( pointer( pPosition ), 5, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE,
    @iMemProtect );

  pPosition^[ 0 ] := $E9;
  pPosition^[ 1 ] := byte( iOffset );
  pPosition^[ 2 ] := byte( iOffset shr 8 );
  pPosition^[ 3 ] := byte( iOffset shr 16 );
  pPosition^[ 4 ] := byte( iOffset shr 24 );
end;

destructor TMethodHook.Destroy;
var
  i : integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to 4 do pPosition^[ i ] := aOriginal[ i ];
  inherited;
end;

end.
```

Comment: I tried above suggested code now it is not hooking up new procedure on system.LoadResString.

Comment: @user4916191 sorry... works fine for me on XE4. Maybe you changed something other from the code in your question above?

Comment: @user4916191 you're right: I misread a comment in your code `{This should return 'new value for ResourceString RS_2' instead of 'XYZ'}` so I thought the wrong output `XYZ` was correct. I delete the answer because it's wrong

Comment: @user4916191 stackoverflow solved; please check my edit

Comment: @ fantaghirocco - Thanks for you comment, got the right direction.

Comment: @user4916191 Glad to help. I apologize for the time lost with the first wrong answer